# TypeError: data.data.map is not a function ,I write for the first time on js and react how to access the fields who will tell you. "n": "adult"

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from "axios";

    function Hooks() {
        const [data, setData] = useState(null)

        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get('url')
                .then((res) => setData(res.data));
        }, []);

        return data ?( <div>
                {data.data.map(home => <div>{home.o}</div>)} //how to access the desired field, I write for the first time help
            </div>
        ):null;
    }

    export default Hooks;
```

```
// json

url
{ 
  "begin": "2021/03/08 16:00:00", 
  "data": {
    "n": "root", 
    "o": [
      {
        "n": "1244", 
        "o": [
          {
            "n": "2021-04-27", 
            "o": [
              {
                "n": "adult", 
                "o": [], 
                "t": "age", 
                "v": 1, 
                "vd": 0
              }, 
              {
                "n": "kid", 
                "o": [], 
                "t": "age", 
                "v": 3, 
                "vd": 3213
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request returns an object and `.map` for arrays, so it won't work with this. You could however do...

```
Object.keys(data.data).map(key => data.data[key].home.o)
```

...as `Object.keys()` returns an array of keys for your object, which you can use to access values in your object the way you would with any object key. For example...

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

//logs the array of keys
console.log(Object.keys(obj))

//logs the value for the key of 'a' in our object
console.log(obj["a"])

//creates an array of keys for our object
const plusOne = Object.keys(obj)
                  //maps through the array of keys
                  .map(key =>
                    //returns the value of each key in our object +1
                    obj[key]+1
                  )

//logs our new array with each value +1
console.log(plusOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data.data is an object, so you can't directly `map` it - you have to make it iterable, like an array. I believe you could do it like this:

```
return data ?( <div>
                {[data.data].map(home => <div>{home.o}</div>)} 
            </div>
        ):null;
```

Here is a testable snippet

```js
let data = {
  "data": {
    "n": "root",
    "o": [{
      "n": "1244",
      "o": [{
        "n": "2021-04-27",
        "o": [{
            "n": "adult",
            "o": [],
            "t": "age",
            "v": 1,
            "vd": 0
          },
          {
            "n": "kid",
            "o": [],
            "t": "age",
            "v": 3,
            "vd": 3213
          }
        ]
      }]
    }]
  }
}

let d = [data.data].map(home => home.o)
console.log(d)
```